# Wordpress: Query 'category_name' given in page custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to query posts from a 'category_name' indicated in the page's custom fields. In other words, can I populate the query below with a custom field value?

```
  <?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => '[from custom field]', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    ...
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Does anyone know how I'd go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, something like this should work:

```
<?php 
$category_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field_name', true );
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => $category_name, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    ...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```